# How to call a stored procedure inside a case

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to execute a stored procedure inside a case statement but im stuck since i cannot execute 2 things like i used to do with a IF statement ! Here's my code :

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.selectBooks
as 
begin

  DECLARE @ArchivedBooks AS TABLE ([Books] varchar(100))

  INSERT INTO @ArchivedBooks(Books)
  select name 
  FROM ArchivedBooks

  SELECT id, 
         bookId, 
         name,
         CASE 
         WHEN (name IN (SELECT Books FROM @ArchivedBooks)) THEN 'archivedBook' 
         // but i want also to execute a stored procedure that will insert the 
         book
         exec dbo.insertBook @name;
        ELSE 'noArchivedBook' as status
  FROM books
end
```

Comment: `CASE` in SQL Server isn't a statement, it's an expression. `CASE` **expressions** can only return a scalar value, they can't execute a stored procedure. If you're looking to return the value from an SP, you'd be better off using a function (in-line table value functions *tend* to perform better). If you post the DDL of your SP `dbo.insertBook` we should be able to help you further; however the name of your SP *implies* you're want to `INSERT` the some data, which you **cannot* do inside a `CASE` expression (or within a `SELECT` statement at all).

Comment: Short answer: You cannot do this.
Longer answer: Write the names out to a temp table (with name as primary key), and then use a WHILE LOOP to invoke the stored procedure for each row in the table. Or use a FAST_FORWARD cursor if you must.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking isn't possible. You'll need to check for and insert the book as a separate step. For example:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.selectBooks
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ArchivedBooksAS TABLE ([Books] varchar(100))

    INSERT INTO @ArchivedBooks(Books)
    SELECT name 
    FROM ArchivedBooks

    IF NOT EXIST (SELECT 0 FROM @ArchivedBooks WHERE Books = @name)
        BEGIN
            EXEC dbo.insertBook @name
        END
    SELECT id, 
           bookId, 
           name,
           CASE WHEN @ArchivedBooks.Book
                IS NULL THEN 'noArchiveBook'
                ELSE 'archivedBook'
                END AS Status
    FROM books
    LEFT JOIN @ArchivedBooks ON @ArchivedBooks.Book = Books.Book
END
```